# Discrete Cumulative distribution for negative binomial function

Tags: probability

Police are to conduct random breath testing on drivers on a busy road one Friday evening. Suppose 3% of the drivers drink and drive at the time. Let X be the number of drivers that police need to test to get the first case of drinking and driving. Let Y be the number of drivers tested to get 3 such cases.

Find P(Y>50)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would say use binomial distribution:

$P(Y=x) = {50\choose x} 0.03^x 0.97^{50-x}$

then $P(Y>50) = [P(0)+P(1)+P(2)]$

Edited - Fixed: Y > 50 if count = 0, 1 or 2 in 50 attempts.

---

Clarification: The event $\{Y> 50\}$ is that for finding *at most* $2$ successes somewhere among the first $50$ of an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials, each with identical success rate $0.03$ (so the third success occurs some unspecified time after).  $$\mathsf P(Y>50)=\binom{50}0 (0.03)^0(0.97)^{50}+\binom{50}1 (0.03)^1(0.97)^{49}+\binom{50}2 (0.03)^2(0.97)^{48}$$

Comment: Thanks, i thought something like this existed but i couldn't seem to find it in my books. Really appreciate it

Comment: @mathman   Apparently I wrote nonsense. I'll fix it.